# CSS Clip-path is not working as expected with multi path shapes

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I created a three path SVG file

[image: my svg file]

I want to use each part (left, middle, right) and clip each of the dive to get this
[image]
from this
[image]

CSS

```
.bgmove {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 70px;
}

.left {
  clip-path: url(#clipLeft);
  background-color: red;
  width: 403px
}

.middle {
clip-path: url(#clipMiddle);
  background-color: black;
  width: 284px;
  left: 373px;
}

.right {
clip-path: url(#clipRight);
  background-color: green;
  width: 473px;
  left: 627px;
}

.left,
.middle,
.right {
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bgmove">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="middle"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>

    <svg height="70" width="1100">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipLeft">
          <path d="M40.4575,70,0,0H362.543L403,70Z" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clipMiddle">
          <path d="M1100,70,1059.55,0H627l40.4506,70Z" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clipRight">
          <path d="M657,70,616.38,0H373l40.62,70Z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can see the result here
https://jsfiddle.net/Zivo/y4srujqe/

as you can see I only the left part is clipped while the the middle and the right are hidden for some reason though I used exactly the same seetings

What am I doing wrong

Comment: why using SVG? a simple polygon can do the job: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div`s are not inside the `svg`. If the shapes are going to be used as a clip-path, their origin is at the `div` itself. That means that `clipMiddle` and `clipRight` are way to the right of where you want them to be. To illustrate that, you can see the paths if you change every clip to `#clipLeft`:

```
.left {
  clip-path: url(#clipLeft);
  background-color: red;
  width: 403px
}

.middle {
  clip-path: url(#clipLeft);
  background-color: black;
  width: 284px;
  left: 373px;
}

.right {
  clip-path: url(#clipLeft);
  background-color: green;
  width: 473px;
  left: 687px;
}
```

See the result at https://jsfiddle.net/vnkgd3r5/. The middle path is not well clipped because it is shorter than the other two.